# Difference between "Geographic Transformation" Options Using ArcGIS Project Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, polygon

In using Arc's Project Tool my Input Feature Class is in the "WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxillary_Sphere" coordinate system.  Once I set the desired "Output Coordinate System" to "GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS" the tool auto-completed the "Geographic Transformation" field to:

NAD_1983_CSRS_To_WGS_1984_2

But I notice there are other options in the dropdown, most notably:

NAD_1983_CSRS_To_WGS_1984_1

What is the difference between these two apparent verions (1 & 2) of transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESRI has a [help article](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005929) on this topic.

This picture is taken directly from that article:

[image: Overview of transformation applications from ESRI article linked above.]